# Will I win or lose money if I toss 2 coins for many times?

Tags: probability, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

> Question: Given 2 fair coins, I am going to toss them simultaneously. If both coins give heads, I lose $\$6$. if both coins give tails, I loss $\$4$. If they have different outcomes, say one is tail another one is head, then I gain $\$5$.
>   If I toss the 2 coins many times, will I win or lose money?

My attempt:

Expected value is zero:

$$\frac{1}{4}\times (-6) + \frac{1}{4}\times (-4) + \frac{1}{2}\times 5 = 0.$$
Does this mean that I will neither win nor lose money, according to law of large numbers?

After checking the answer, it seems that I need to calculate variance as well as it will go to infinity as sample size increases.

Will the variance affect anything?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: The variance does not affect the expected value. The variance comes into play if you compare this game with an alternative situation (game). If this  game has an expected value of 0 as well and a smaller variance we usually prefer the game with the smaller variance. In general it is supposed that people are risk-avers.

Comment: It is common to also consider what happens if you or who you are playing against only have a finite amount of money.  You can't lose money if you have no money to lose after all.

Comment: Say $S_n$ is the amount you win after $n$ repetitions. LLN shows that $S_n/n\to0$, not quite the same as "will neither win nor lose".  The variance says something about how large you'd expect $|S_n|$ to be.

Comment: I'm curious, what did the official answer say about the variance?  I.e. why was it even mentioned?  The most typical (basic) interpretation of the question "will I win or lose money" is that it is asking about expected value, in which case the variance is irrelevant.  There are more advanced (non-standard?) interpretations which involve variance.

Comment: The author mentioned variance os to justify that the more tosses we throw,we are unlikely to continue playing due to  large variance. In other words, ome should not toss too many times.

Comment: "One should not toss too many times" $\leftarrow$ that assumes the player is risk averse, which is true for most real people but not for an abstract person in a math problem. :)